# Interop PowerPoint notes pages

Tags: pdf, c#-4.0, powerpoint, powerpoint-interop

Does interop have a way to change the view of a PowerPoint presentation to notes pages? I'm building an application to automatically convert a large amount of pptx files to pdf and would much prefer the pdf's to be in note page view but I can't seem to find anything in the documentation for doing so? If interop doesn't support this, does anyone know another api with this function?

Answer (score 0):

Have a look here. It's specific to VBA but the parameters should be the same, I think.

https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/vba/powerpoint-vba/articles/presentation-exportasfixedformat-method-powerpoint

You'd want to specify `PpPrintOutputType` and set it to `ppPrintOutputNotesPages` (a PowerPoint constant equal to 5)